# How can interpret ~ symbol in this command line?

Tags: command-line, permissions

While I am installing Jenkins and Ansible, I see this command from tutorial.

```
sudo cp ~/.kube/config ~jenkins/.kube/
sudo chown -R jenkins: ~jenkins/.kube/
```

sudo cp ~/.kube/config `~`jenkins/.kube/

sudo chown -R jenkins: `~`jenkins/.kube/

~/.kube/config means the `home diectory`/.kube/config file.

But as for `~jenkins`, I don't know what does it mean.

Can you kindly let me know?

Comment: Thank you , great !!!

Comment: @N0rbert,        sudo chown -R `jenkins:` ~jenkins/.kube/          execute this, then what group do those files have finally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` means home directory of the **current** user (the one calling the command).

`~username` means home directory of the user `username`.

Comment: Thx, i can't upvote for little reputation

Comment: now can upvote you